# Button Click Handler Not Executing

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, webforms, event-handling

On a webform, I've got a Button inside a Placeholder control. Initiallty, I set its Click event declaratively in markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmitAgain" OnClick="btnSubmitAgain_Click" CssClass="button iconButton SubmitAgainbtn" />
```

However, everytime I click this button it bypasses the defined handler (the breakpoint I set is never hit) and behaves like a generic `submit` button and causes a postback. My handler clears a session variable and then Redirects back to itself so does not cause a postback).

I've got an almost identical version of this form which behaves correctly and is, to all intents and purposes, identical code. The handler works everytime in this one :-(

Try as I might I haven't been able to get this to work correctly. Can anyone suggest anything I could look out for? I just don't understand why the event won't fire via the Handler ...

Comment: is <compilation debug="true"> in the web.config?

Comment: Yep. And the debugger will hit the same code in the almost-identical version of this form

Comment: put a breakpoint in the Page_Init event and step through it.  Perhaps there is a redirect happening before your click handler is being called, or their is an exception happening and it is exiting before it gets to the handler.

Comment: 1. I haven't defined a `Page_Init` handler.  
2. No exceptions are being raised (I have got an app-wide mechanism for handling/logging exceptions)

Answer (score -2):

It works fine.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="resubmit" ID="btnSubmitAgain"  
    CssClass="button iconButton SubmitAgainbtn" onclick="btnSubmitAgain_Click" />  
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Note that I added some text to the button so it could be seen:  **Text="resubmit"**

Comment: Your response wasn't terribly helpful.

Comment: It shows working code.  How is the non-working code different?